# SQL Error - Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I am trying to create a procedure that takes in the value using the cursor but encounter error "Must declare the scalar variable "@labtests"." But I have done that. 
I have created the type before creating the procedure. 
create type labTestCodeType as table (testcode char(4));

```
create procedure usp_orderLab
@patientID char(9),
@testDate smalldatetime,
@doctorID int,
@labtests labTestCodeType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
declare labTestCodeCursor Cursor for
select testcode from @labTests
OPEN labTestCodeCursor
FETCH Next from labTestCodeCursor INTO @labtests
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO LabOrder (patientID,testDate,doctorID) values (@patientID,@testDate,@doctorID)
INSERT INTO TestOrdered (patientID,testDate,testCode) values (@patientID,@testDate,@labtests)
Fetch next from labTestCodeCursor INTO @labtests    
END
CLOSE labTestCodeCursor
DEALLOCATE labTestCodeCursor
END
```

Because I am trying to input different TestCode in one query.

```
declare @test labTestCodeType
insert into @test values('S023'), ('B001')
exec usp_orderLab 'T0300001F', '12 Dec 2018', null,@test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is :

```
FETCH Next from labTestCodeCursor INTO @labtests
```

`@labtests` is a table type. You can't fetch into a table type. You need a scalar variable.

Change it to :

```
declare @testcode char(4)
FETCH Next from labTestCodeCursor INTO @testcode
```

and also this part :

```
INSERT INTO TestOrdered (patientID, testDate, testCode) 
                 values (@patientID, @testDate, @testcode)
```

Question: Why are you using cursor when it can be done with a set based query ?

EDIT :

A non-cursor solution

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO LabOrder (patientID, testDate, doctorID) 
              values (@patientID, @testDate, @doctorID)

INSERT INTO TestOrdered (patientID,testDate,testCode) 
SELECT @patientID, @testDate, testcode
FROM   @labtests

END
```

Comment: Please refer to my answer in y question above. Thanks your answer has helped me to solve the error.